# Excel Userform call checkbox by name

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I have a form that sets up a list of labels with content and an accompanying checkbox on initialisation.

I want to check the value of a checkbox when a button is clicked.

How do I reference back to the checkbox - I have called the checkbox a number (the value of i) when they are created.

Code to add the checkbox:

```
Sub addLabel()
    Dim theCheck As Object
    Dim theLabel As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    LastRow = Worksheets("Assumptions").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        Set theLabel = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Assumption" & i, True)
        With theLabel
            .Name = "Assumption" & i
            .Caption = Worksheets("Assumptions").Range("B" & i).Value ' &    labelCounter
            .Left = 156
            .Width = 500
            .Top = 138 + i * 20
        End With
        Set theCheck = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", i, True)
        With theCheck
            .Name = i
            .Left = 140
            .Width = 10
            .Top = 138 + i * 20
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

My ultimate goal is to check which checkbox is 'True' and then IF true enter the accompanying label content into a worksheet.

My main struggle at the moment is how to reference the checkboxes by name (e.g. loop through them all where they are called 1-10 for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make reference of an object in your form you can use the following syntax

```
<Name of your form>.<Name of your control>
```

In you can I believe that something like `UserForm1.1` but **this is not a great idea to call your checkbox only with a number, give it with a proper name**.

I strongly recommend that you change

```
With theCheck
    .Name = i 'This is not great
    .Left = 140
    .Width = 10
    .Top = 138 + i * 20
End With
```

By something more explicit like

```
With theCheck
    .Name = "cb" & i 'Not great but better
    .Left = 140
    .Width = 10
    .Top = 138 + i * 20
End With
```

---

### Loop through each Checkbox in your form

To go through each Checkbox and check if it's checked or not, you can use something like this

```
'Go through each control in your UserForm
For Each myControl In UserForm1.Controls
    'If the current control is a Checkbox
    If (TypeName(myControl) = "Checkbox") Then
        'Check it's value
        If (myControl.Value = True) Then
            'Do whatever you want
            'You can access your checkbox properties with myControl.YOUR_PROPERTY
        End If
    End If
Next myControl
```

Comment: can you not simplify to If TypeName(myControl) = "Checkbox" and myControl.Value = True Then.....

Comment: @QHarr No you can't. If you try to you'll get an error saying this property or method is not supported.

Comment: Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: @QHarr Because a Control Object has no Value property